# How to have a single grid background in "cowplot" using plot_grid() combining two plots together? in R language

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot, gridlines

**In R language I want to have a single background horizontal lines (background grid) to make it easier to identify the columns. I will provide an example in the R code.**

```
# install.packages("cowplot")
library(ggplot2) 
library(cowplot)



df <- data.frame(
  supp = rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each = 3),
  dose = rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"), 2),
  len = c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5)
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = dose, y = len))+
  geom_col(aes(fill = supp), width = 0.7)+ coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme(  legend.position = "bottom",
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
         plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA))
p

plot_grid(p, p, align = 'h', ncol = 2, rel_widths = c(5, 5))
```

[image: The output of the two plot like that]

**I want to make a (background grid) in the form of grey horizontal lines that separates each column likee in the screenshot that will provided [image: here]
I want the background pass by the two plots in the plot_grid with no separation. Because my original plots will be like that but more advance providing the columns names in the first plot only and these lines helps to know what column is that in the second column by looking at the first plot names.
Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to remove the space between your plots by setting the right/left `plot.margin` to zero, setting the `axis.ticks.length` to zero and by setting the y axis title to `NULL`. Finally I use `geom_hline` to add the "grid" lines.

Note: I switched the role of `x` and `y` to get rid of `coord_flip`. Makes it easier (for my brain (;) to do the adjustments.

```r
# install.packages("cowplot")
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

df <- data.frame(
  supp = rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each = 3),
  dose = rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"), 2),
  len = c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5)
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(y = dose, x = len)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = supp), width = 0.7) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0:3 + .5) +
  labs(x = "", y = NULL) +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_blank(), 
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "pt"),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA)
  )

plot_grid(
  p + theme(plot.margin = margin(5.5, 0, 5.5, 5.5)),
  p + theme(plot.margin = margin(5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 0)),
  align = "h", ncol = 2, rel_widths = c(5, 5)
)
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate you effort, Thanks a lot.

Comment: The code worked perfectly with me. but after a while, I got this error. Can you please help me with it ?

Comment: ! Theme element `plot.margin` must be a unit vector of length 4.
Backtrace:
  1. cowplot::plot_grid(...)
  2. cowplot::align_plots(...)
  3. base::lapply(...)
  4. cowplot FUN(X[[i]], ...)
  6. cowplot:::as_gtable.default(x)
     ...
  9. ggplot2::ggplotGrob(plot)
 11. ggplot2:::ggplot_gtable.ggplot_built(ggplot_build(x))
 12. ggplot2:::plot_theme(plot)
 13. base::mapply(validate_element, theme, names(theme), MoreArgs = list(element_tree = get_element_tree()))
 14. ggplot2 `<fn>`(dots[[1L]][[83L]], dots[[2L]][[83L]], element_tree = `<named list>`)